# Feathers js - how to login by google

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, oauth, feathersjs

I am following the [doc](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/google.html#application-client-and-secret) to create google strategy.

When I access http://localhost:3030/oauth/google through browser, below error occurs:

```
Error Code 400： redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://localhost/oauth/google/callback, 
does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 
To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/12345678-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=xxxxyyyy
```

[image]

authentication.js

```
const { AuthenticationService, AuthenticationBaseStrategy, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { expressOauth } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');

const axios = require('axios');
const { OAuthStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');

class GoogleStrategy extends OAuthStrategy {
  async getEntityData(profile) {
    const baseData = await super.getEntityData(profile);
    // this will grab the picture and email address of the Google profile
    return {
      ...baseData,
      email: profile.email
    };
  }
}

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());
  authentication.register('google', new GoogleStrategy());
 
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
};
```

config/local.json

```
{
    "authentication": {
      "entity": "user",
      "service": "users",
      "secret": "SA3c59SscyH6TscABCdeFG=",
      "authStrategies": [
        "jwt",
        "local",
        "google"
      ],
      "jwtOptions": {
        "header": {
          "typ": "access"
        },
        "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
        "issuer": "feathers",
        "algorithm": "HS256",
        "expiresIn": "1d"
      },
      "local": {
        "usernameField": "email",
        "passwordField": "password"
      },
      "oauth": {
        "google": {
          "key": "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "secret": "ASDFGgh"
        }
      }
    },
}
```

**Update 1**
Fixed issue by adding `https://localhost/oauth/google/callback` in `Authorized redirect URIs`.

Now the website redirect to `Select Account` Page.

After I click my account, the website is redirected to `https://localhost/oauth/google/callback?code=4/abcd-xxx-xxxxx-xxx&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20openid&authuser=0&hd=myDomain.com&prompt=consent`

[image]

**Update 2**

Updated local.json and add `redirect_uri` field

```
      "oauth": {
        "redirect": "/",
        "google": {
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3030/auth/google/callback", // add here
          "key": "abcd.googleusercontent.com",
          "secret": "xxxx",
          "scope": [
            "email",
            "profile",
            "openid"
          ],
          "nonce": true
        }
      }
```

It can now redirect to `http://localhost:3030/auth/google/callback?code=xxx&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&hd=myDomain.com&prompt=consent#`

It shows `404 Page Not Find` instead of redirecting to `/`
[image]

**Update 3**

Now the website redirects to `https://localhost/oauth/google/authenticate#`, I know it should be `https://localhost:3030/oauth/google/authenticate`, but I don't know how and where Feather/Google Cloud Platform can set it

**Update 4**

Finally successfully redirecting to `www.google.com#error=Field%20password%20does%20not%20exist.%20(required)`,
is it kind of an error?

```
    "oauth": {
      "redirect": "www.google.com",
      "google": {
        "key": "<Google OAuth key>",
        "secret": "<Google OAuth secret>",
        "scope": [
          "email",
          "profile",
          "openid"
        ],
        "nonce": true,
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3030/oauth/google/callback",
        "callback": "/oauth/google/authenticate"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Issue number one redirect uri

Redirect URI must exactly match the location you are sending

Your app is sending

```
https://localhost/oauth/google/callback
```

You have only added the following as a valid redirect uri

```
http://localhost:3030/auth/google/callback
```

The solution is to take https://localhost/oauth/google/callback and add it as a valid redirect uri in Google Developer console.

## issue number two.

Site cannot be reached.

Your application has told google that you are preparted to respond to the authorization code form the authorization server at the following endpoint

```
https://localhost/oauth/google/callback?code=4/abcd-xxx-xxxxx-xxx&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20openid&authuser=0&hd=myDomain.com&prompt=consent
```

Your site does not appear to be able to handle that response.  I would check that the callback file exists.

Comment: Same answer 404 means page not found.  The page does not exist.   https://localhost/oauth/google/callback  This needs to be on YOUR machine and contain the code which can handle the authorization call back.